# Javascript const list combining multiple keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, list, constants

I am working on node js project where I am defining const list with multiple keys having same values. Can we combine it like we do it in switch..case statements if multiple cases are having same values.

```
const SampleList = {
  1:{
    0:new Set(3,4,5),
  },
  2:{
    0:new Set(3,4,5),
  }
};
```

Can we combine these 2 items to avoid duplicate code something like

```
const SampleList = {
  1:
  2:{
    0:new Set(3,4,5),
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define the property value before creating the object and use that value for each property:

```
const mySet = {
  0: new Set(3,4,5),
};

const SampleList = {
  1: mySet,
  2: mySet
};
```

Note of course that both properties reference *the same object*.  So changes made to that object would be reflected in both properties.  Which would have been the case in the otherwise incorrect syntax you were envisioning as well.

If you want them to be different instances of an object then instead of defining just the value you can define a function which creates and returns a value:

```
const createSet = () => ({
  0: new Set(3,4,5),
});

const SampleList = {
  1: createSet(),
  2: createSet()
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was really helpful